# Append data to localStorage object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, local-storage

I'm trying, unsuccessfully, to add a new object to a current localStorage object. Instead of, at the end, having two sets of data in localStorage, I get the last one. Any insight on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
// add the first student
var newStudent = [{
     "name":        "John",
     "age":         21,
     "nationality": "Spanish"
 }];

localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(newStudent));


// Retrieve the object from storage to add a new student
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem("students");
var stored          = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);

// add a new student
var newStudent2 = [{
    "name":        "Mary",
    "age":         20,
    "nationality": "German"
}];
var stored = Object.assign(stored, newStudent2);

// Update the storage
localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(stored));
var result = localStorage.getItem("students");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Have you tried something like: window.localStorage.attr = value or just localStorage.attr = value?

Comment: Are you attempting to have an array of objects within localStorage? You're currently putting each object in it's own array, which is a little odd.

Comment: Yes, I'm attempting to have an array of objects, but only the last is saved.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should store array, not an object;

```
var students = [];

var student1 = { s: 1 };

students.push(student1);

localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(students));

var stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("students"));

var student2 = { s: 2 };

stored.push(student2);

localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(stored));

var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("students"));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey. That really works. Now I understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You are replacing the stored object by newStudent2 when fetching it back from localStorage:

```
var newStudent = [{
     "name":        "John",
     "age":         21,
     "nationality": "Spanish"
 }];

localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(newStudent));

var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem("students");
var stored          = JSON.parse(retrievedObject); <----newStudent1

var newStudent2 = [{
    "name":        "Mary",
    "age":         20,
    "nationality": "German"
}];


var stored = Object.assign(stored, newStudent2); <----Here newStudent1 is replaced by newStudent2


localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(stored)); // Here newStudent2 is replacing old object on localStorage
var result = localStorage.getItem("students");

console.log(result);
```

You can instead try creating an array of objects and appending them whenever creating a new one.

```
var objects = []
objects.push(stored) 

localStorage.setItem('students', JSON.stringify(objects))
```

Comment: Yes, those were the issues. Thanks Diego

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Object.assign()` wrong. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for info about it.

Do you really need `newStudent2` to be an array of a single object? If not you can simply do `stored.push(newStudent2)`, where `newStudent2` is an object and not an array with a single object.

So, something like:

```
var students = [];

// add the first student
// Notice how the student is now an object and not an array containing an object.
var newStudent = {
     "name":        "John",
     "age":         21,
     "nationality": "Spanish"
 };

students.push(newStudent);

localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(students));


// Retrieve the object from storage to add a new student
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem("students");
var stored          = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);

// add a new student
// Notice how the student is now an object and not an array containing an object.
var newStudent2 = {
    "name":        "Mary",
    "age":         20,
    "nationality": "German"
};

stored.push(newStudent2);

// Update the storage
localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(stored));
var result = localStorage.getItem("students");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi Mitch. thanks. The stored.push() also seems to work. Sergey's solution helped me understand what I was doing wrong and it was very basic. :(

Comment: @McRui You are welcome. I updated the answer in the meantime

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) `The Object.assign() method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object`

in your case:
`var stored = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);` return array, you can just `push` new object to array: `stored.push(newStudent2);` and when set `stored` to `localStorage`.

Comment: Yes, that was one of the first errors I got because they were not writable. Thanks zooblin